# Getting the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    var tmpDiv = '#difdiv' + i;
    var tmpButton = '#difButton' + i;
    $(tmpDiv).css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: $('#map').position().top - 16
    });
    $(tmpDiv).css('z-index', 3000);
    $(tmpDiv).css('width', '100%');

    $(tmpButton).hover(
        function () {
            $(tmpDiv).fadeIn(200);
        }, function () {
            $(tmpDiv).fadeOut(200);
        }
    );
}
```

I use this loop to add a hover dif to a variable amount of buttons.
When I use this code, every jQuery-Element gets the "'#difdiv' + i". And at the end every buttons fades the same difdiv in and out. In this case difdiv3.
How can I access the value give it to the jQuery element instead of the variable?

Comment: Can you gives the problem instead? It will be easier to help that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the variable reference. Easy way around it is to take what is inside the loop and stuff it into a function and call it.

```
function createButton(i) {
    var tmpDiv = '#difdiv' + i;
    var tmpButton = '#difButton' + i;
    $(tmpDiv).css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: $('#map').position().top - 16
    });
    $(tmpDiv).css('z-index', 3000);
    $(tmpDiv).css('width', '100%');

    $(tmpButton).hover(
        function () {
            $(tmpDiv).stop().fadeIn(200);  //added stop
        }, function () {
            $(tmpDiv).stop().fadeOut(200); //added stop
        }
    );
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    createButton(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is the best possibility to solve the problem. But it works fine.